# Calculate correlations between two different tables with different structures

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have two tables, on containing a column of one value 'num1' per date, and another containing one value *per name* 'num2' per date. I'm interested in calculating the correlation between each name's 'num2' value and 'num1', but I'm unsure of whether or not I need to break the 'data2' table up into distinct tables for each name, or if there's a clean way to do this.

```
data1 = {'date':  ['2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'], 'num1': ['.024', '.035', '.04']}
data2 = {'date':  ['2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05','2022-01-05','2022-01-05'], 'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'num2':['20','200','149','36','174','400','45','100','12']}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1).set_index('date')
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2).set_index('date')
print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Is there a way to calculate correlations between num1 and num2 for each name without manipulating these tables heavily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.corr.html) after ensuring having numerical values and joining the dataframes:

```
out = (data2
  .astype({'num2': int})
  .join(data1.astype({'num1': float}))
  .groupby('name').corr()
)
```

output:

```
                num2      num1
name                          
name1 num2  1.000000  0.998599
      num1  0.998599  1.000000
name2 num2  1.000000 -0.885346
      num1 -0.885346  1.000000
name3 num2  1.000000 -0.141869
      num1 -0.141869  1.000000
```

Comment: A bit of an extension question, but is there a way to sort by correlation values between num1 and num2 so that the 'name' index is in descending order with highest correlations at the top?

Comment: you can try to add `.stack().sort_values(ascending=False)`, or as you have only 2 values: `['num2'].sort_values(ascending=False)`